# Showing a module only on first page of Category Blog

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am using this code to show a module inside blog.php:

```
 <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition myModule}'); ?>
```

How can I show it only on the first page of the category blog?
I want to combine the above code with the code below:

```
<?php if (!JRequest::getInt('start') < 1) { ?>
................
<?php } ?>
```

but for some reason I am not doing it right.
Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you passing a variable (via hyperlink or form submission) that equates to `start=0` or `start=1` etc.? Your conditional logic is a little twisted.  I think you should pull that `!` out of the expression (or remove `< 1`) -- you don't want to flip the evaluated boolean value that is generated.  Please confirm that you are receiving a value from JRequest.  What is your current output? Any errors/warnings/notices being generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in logic check. Now it runs when `start` is `>= 1`. You can remove the `!` operator or the comparison (`< 1`).

Some other thoughts:

`JRequest` is deprecated. `JInput` should be used instead of it. But in this case it's best to use values from state.

You can render the module using document's renderer instead of plugin shortcode. This will prevent content plugins from running on generated module content, which may or may not be desirable.

```
<?php if (!$this->state->get('list.start')) : ?>
    <?php echo JFactory::getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')->render('myModule'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To show only on 2nd page, compare `list.start` value to `list.limit` value. Remember, this isn't 100% reliable because users can manipulate this by changing the URL.

```
<?php if ($this->state->get('list.start') == $this->state->get('list.limit')) : ?>
    <?php echo JFactory::getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')->render('myModule'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfect. just a tip: how is the code if I want (i.e.) to be only in the 2nd page?

Comment: If `start=0` is the first page and `start=1` is the second page, you use `<?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('start') == 1) { echo JFactory::getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')->render('myModule'); } ?>`

Comment: It's tricky because there are no defined page numbers in list views. Instead there are `start` and `limit` parameters, both of which can be manipulated manually. Suppose, you have 5 item limit per page. Users can just append `start=3` to URL and end up on a page that is neither 1st (doesn't start at 0) nor 2nd (doesn't start at 5). But if that doesn't matter, use `list.limit` and `list.start` values from state. See updated answer.